# how do I create facebook login callback in separate class android

Tags: android

I am working on an app which has Facebook login functionality. I am using Facebook login. I would like to have Facebook CallBack in different classes, so I can get retrieve facebook ID and image etc.. But how do I do this? This is my LoginActivity class:

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
LoginButton loginButton;
TextView textView;
CallbackManager callbackManager;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_login_btn);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();



    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainMenu.class);
            startActivity (myIntent);
            finish(); //if you want to do not use this
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            textView.setText("Login Cancelled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            textView.setText("Login Failed");
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}
```

}

and I have a Profile Class, where I want to access Facebook Profile Picture and email address. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you inherit FacebookCallback like:

`ProfileClass extends FacebookCallback`

Then pass an instance of ProfileClass into:

`loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, profileClass`);

In your `ProfileClass` implement `onSuccess(), onCancel() and onError()` methods and write your desired logic in them.

Comment: do I add an instance of ProfileClass into my LoginActivity? and also my ProfileClass already extends AppCompactActivity